# Attempting to make a Guess the number game i made on Python to use a GUI. but the program not responding when ran

Tags: python, tkinter

The code should just display the basic GUI elements but on run it only displays `titlelbl` and is not responding. i suspected it might be the way i have the loops but am not too sure. would love the insight thanks!

basicaly want a text field to type guess, a summit button and then have a label to display if you're too high or low and display tries left until loss or win

```py
import random
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Guess Number")

window.geometry('1000x800')

rand1 = 1
rand2 = 100
randNum = random.randint(rand1,rand2)
gameEnd = False
answer = "a"
allotedTries = 4
tries = 3
while gameEnd == False:
    
#Builds elements of GUI 

    titlelbl = Label(window, text="Guess Number from 1 to 100!", font=("Arial Bold", 50))   
    titlelbl.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="NW")
    titlelbl.grid_propagate(0)
    titlelbl.update()
    titlelbl.place(x=500, y=125, anchor="center")

    infolbl = Label(window, textvariable = tries, font=("Arial Bold", 25))
    infolbl.place(x=500, y=550, anchor="center")
    
#begining of game logic

    guess = int(input("Guess a number from 1 to 100 " ))
    tries -= 1

    if guess == randNum:
        answer = "Correct"
        gameEnd = True
    elif guess > randNum:
        answer = "High"
    elif guess < randNum:
        answer = "Low"
    if tries == 0 :
        print("Sorry! Ran out of Tries")
        gameEnd = True
        break
            
    #displaying of results 

    if answer == "Correct":
        print("Correct! Winner ")
        break
    elif answer == "High":
        print("Too High; Tries Left: ")
        print(tries)
        infolbl.update()
    elif answer == "Low":
        print("Too Low; Tries Left: ")
        print(tries)
        infolbl.update()
    
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the requirement that you specified

> basicaly want a text field to type guess, a summit button and then have a label to display if you're too high or low and display tries left until loss or win

There is no point of having an infinite loop to achieve this. Add the widgets that you mentioned, create a function that checks the input and updates the label accordingly, bind that to the button. Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) and first try to figure it out yourself, Stack Overflow isn't a platform to get your code written.

As of the current issues with your code:

- Infinite while loop keeps the main thread continuously busy, causing the window to not respond.
- `tries` is not a `IntVar()` which is a tkinter variable for storing integers and can be used with `textvariable` parameter, you will need to use the `.set()` method to assign it a value. Since none of this is done, your label is placed but has nothing to display.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop that will run forever before you open the window with `window.mainloop()`. So you should put the `while gameEnd == False` into a [thread](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/), then call `window.mainloop`. So you can call that function main and use `threading.thread()` to run main while running your window.